# Connecting my RS232 Cable to my NXP - LPC1313FBD48

Tags: microcontroller, rs232

I recently bought an LPC1313FBD48 Microcontroller and an FTDI TTL-232R-3V3 cable. How can I connect the cable to the MCU? I cannot fit the pins of the MCU into the ports of the cable.

[image: my microcontroller and cable]

Would I need copper wire to connect the cable ends to the pins of the mcu?

Comment: A MCU in SMD package is useless without a [PCB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printed_circuit_board).

Comment: Perhaps the bigger question is how you will connect the MCU to anything else, once you've programmed it.

Comment: @TurboJ Should I put the MCU on the PCB with solder paste then add wires from the MCU through the PCB and have them lead out of the PCB so I can have loose wires sticking out of the pcb? That way I could connect the loose wires to the cable.

Comment: @coder404: *which* PCB?? Your photo shows only a chip, if you have a PCB, why don't you show it???

Comment: @WoutervanOoijen all I have is the MCU. I do not have a PCB

Comment: @Coder404: then how did you plan to use that chip?? Better think about that first, that will likely solve you ISP connection problem too.

Comment: @WoutervanOoijen Sorry about all of the confusion. I am very new to this and I couldn't find any resources anywhere other than SE.

Comment: @Coder404: No offence at all, but you are asking a series of tiny questions, where you should have asked an overall question like "how should I start developing with a microcontroller". Now you are stuck on a particular bare chip, which is IMO not the best choice for a beginner.

Comment: @WoutervanOoijen Ok. What do you think I should do?

Comment: Depends on what you want. For instance, get an LPC1114 in DIP, or get an LPC expresso board, like Phil Frost shows. In both cases, get a solderless breadboard too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That looks like an LQFP-48 package. As you have aptly observed, most devices are physically incompatible. You will either have to design and make a PCB, or obtain one someone else already designed.

The [product page](https://www.nxp.com/products/processors-and-microcontrollers/arm-based-processors-and-mcus/general-purpose-mcus/lpc1300-cortex-m3/entry-level-32-bit-microcontroller-mcu-based-on-arm-cortex-m3-core:LPC1313FBD48) has a number of demo boards, like this one:

[image: demo board]
<sub>(source: [nxp.com](http://www.nxp.com/scale-image/w-170/resources/demoboard/mainvisual/1320941906128.jpeg))</sub>

These usually have the pins available as .100" headers or something similarly large and easy to access. They also usually contain all the peripheral devices (a crystal, reset button, maybe a voltage regulator, maybe some LEDs for status indication) you'd want to play with the device. Some have more specific peripherals (USB, Ethernet, sensors, displays...) Search the internet. There are hundreds.

There are also [PCBs available](https://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=lqfp-48+breakout&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) for common surface mount packages that break the pins out into .100" headers, to which you can then attach [standard .100" pitch connectors](http://www.molex.com/catalog/web_catalog/pdfs/C.pdf) (your cable has one such connector). Some (though not the one pictured) have the headers arranged in two rows, designed to attach to a breadboard or fit in a [DIP socket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_in-line_package).

[image: breakout board]

You can also solder tiny wires onto each pin if you have good tools, eyesight, and a steady hand. I wouldn't recommend it, though. Besides being tedious work, it will be a mess.